# What is the best way of handling multi dimensional arrays in Knockout JS?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-validation

**What is the standard way of dealing with multidimensional arrays with Knockout?**

Let's say you want to generate a dynamic table with KnockoutJS.  The table rows and columns are generated from observableArrays.  The data inside of each cell are also observables (data bound to textboxes).  The data inside each cell also needs to get validated with knockout validation.

I am using something like that to generate the value of my textboxes:

```
data-bind="value: $root.qty[$index()][$parentContext.$index()]"
```

This is inside two foreach for the tbody:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.styleColors">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: StyleColorName, visible: $root.showFirstColumn"></td>
        <!-- ko foreach: $root.sizes -->
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="qty" data-bind="value: $root.qty[$index()][$parentContext.$index()]"/>
            </td>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

It works well, but I need to be able to change the data dynamically depending on what item I am editing.  As soon as I change the number of columns or rows, this causes all sort of problems.  I reduced a lot of those problems using the [throttle](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/throttle-extender.html) extender by making the rendering wait for both rows and columns observable before rendering.

Each time I change the currently edited item, I regenerate the qty[][] multidimensionnal array using simple javascript arrays and each actual value is an observable.

Here is an example of a tipical problem I have.  For this particular example, I validate a min and max value for my quantity values (the cells).  But I get the following exeption (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rules' of undefined) when I rebind a table containing less rows or less columns.  I am changing the observableArrays for the rows and columns, the binding data-bind="$root.qty[$index()][$parentContext.$index()]" is not valid anymore because one of the indexes is out of bound.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't really answer your question without seeing more viewmodel code, but your way sounds complicated. - unless you can figure out how to control in what order knockout evaluates add/removals you're going to run into indexing problems. I'll tell you how I solved the table problem though.

Also - ie, especially 8 downwards, is very finicky about javascript code modifying tables. test test test!

I basically modified sandersons simple grid - I'd check that out and see if it works for you at all.

https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/tree/gh-pages/examples/resources

Instead of doing a multidimensional array, have one array that is your columns and then another array for your rows. Each item in the row array is actually an object with the different column names as keys and the objects as the value.

So....

```
//two columns
this.columns = ko.observableArray(["Column1","Column2"]);

//two Rows
this.rowData = ko.observableArray([
{Column1:{StyleColorName:"Top Left"},Column2:{StyleColorName:"Top Right"}},
{Column1:{StyleColorName:"Bottom Left"},Column2:{StyleColorName:"Bottom Right"}}
]);
```

Aaannd the markup

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-bind="visible:showFirstColumn">First Column</th>
        <!-- ko foreach: $root.sizes -->
        <th data-bind="text:$data" ></th>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: rowData">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: StyleColorName, visible: $root.showFirstColumn"></td>
        <!-- ko foreach: columns -->
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="qty" data-bind="value:$parent[$data].StyleColorName()"/>
            </td>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
</tbody>
```